# How to prioritize the route in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making React app, and I have some Routers.

```
const App = () => {
  return  (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <div>
        <Route path="/LogIn" render={() => <LogIn />} />
        <Route path="/Shop" render={() => <GoodsContainer />} />
        <Route path="/Delivery" render ={() => <Delivery />} />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I open my page for the first time, there're only `Header`component and `Footer` component, and It's logically because the url has not contain pathes which I have set to the Routes.

So, **my question is** how to show always , for example the Route `<Route path="/Shop" render={() => <GoodsContainer />} />` when the user open the site.

***`Redirect` isn't my solution.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check @Yousef answer for this , Also if you arent passing any props, then do this instead. Don't forget to give the `exact`

```
 <Route path={["/", "/Shop"]} exact render={GoodsContainer} />
```

But if you are passing then do this

```
 <Route path={["/", "/Shop"]} exact render={(props)=> <GoodsContainer {...props} />} />
```

Answer (score 2):

`path` prop could either be a string or an array of strings. You can define multiple paths for `GoodsContainer` component using an array of strings as a value for `path` prop

```
<Route path={["/", "/Shop"]} render={() => <GoodsContainer />} />
```

and don't forget to either use `exact` prop on `Route` component or wrap all `Route` component with `Switch` component otherwise `/` path will match all other routes.

Comment: I've used this in Node js, I didn't know we could use in React, awsome.

Comment: In this case, the component does not disappear when I change the route

Comment: either use `exact` or `Switch` otherwise `/` will match all other routes.